# Can I use CountVectorizer in scikit-learn to count frequency of documents that were not used to extract the tokens?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I have been working with the `CountVectorizer` class in scikit-learn.

I understand that if used in the manner shown below, the final output will consist of an array containing counts of features, or tokens.

These tokens are extracted from a set of keywords, i.e.

```
tags = [
  "python, tools",
  "linux, tools, ubuntu",
  "distributed systems, linux, networking, tools",
]
```

The next step is:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vec = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize)
data = vec.fit_transform(tags).toarray()
print data
```

Where we get

```
[[0 0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0 1 0]]
```

This is fine, but my situation is just a little bit different.

I want to extract the features the same way as above, but I don't want the rows in `data` to be the same documents that the features were extracted from.

In other words, how can I get counts of another set of documents, say,

```
list_of_new_documents = [
  ["python, chicken"],
  ["linux, cow, ubuntu"],
  ["machine learning, bird, fish, pig"]
]
```

And get:

```
[[0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

I have read the documentation for the `CountVectorizer` class, and came across the `vocabulary` argument, which is a mapping of terms to feature indices.  I can't seem to get this argument to help me, however.

Any advice is appreciated.
PS:  all credit due to [Matthias Friedrich's Blog](http://blog.mafr.de/2012/04/15/scikit-learn-feature-extractio/) for the example I used above.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You're right that `vocabulary` is what you want.  It works like this:

```
>>> cv = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer(vocabulary=['hot', 'cold', 'old'])
>>> cv.fit_transform(['pease porridge hot', 'pease porridge cold', 'pease porridge in the pot', 'nine days old']).toarray()
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

So you pass it a dict with your desired features as the keys.

If you used `CountVectorizer` on one set of documents and then you want to use the set of features from those documents for a new set, use the `vocabulary_` attribute of your original CountVectorizer and pass it to the new one.  So in your example, you could do

```
newVec = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vec.vocabulary_)
```

to create a new tokenizer using the vocabulary from your first one.

Comment: Thanks, this looks great! For the first solution:  should the vocabulary always be a dict, not list? Correct me if I'm wrong, but the counts (0, 1, 2) seem irrelevant.  The second method you outlined looks perhaps a little clearer.

Comment: @MattO'Brien: You're right, it can be a list, I misread the documentation.  I edited my answer.  In the second method, though, it is a dict, because that's what the `vocabulary_` method of a fitted vectorizer is.

Comment: BrenBarn, your answer saved me a lot of time.  Seriously. Thanks for being on this site.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding something, but rather than initializing a new `CountVectorizer` with the original vocabulary, could you not just call `.transform()` on the new document set with the original vectorizer?

Comment: I have a large list (n > 10000)of strings in which each string contains 100K to 110K words. how to make this countVectorizer fast for such data. Is this works by using all cores

Comment: for anybody having problem with the `vocabulary` param, `CountVectorizer()` has a `lowercase=True` default setting so you have to set it to `lowercase=False` if your custom vocabulary list is uppercase.

Answer (score 9):

You should call `fit_transform` or just `fit` on your original vocabulary source so that the vectorizer learns a vocab.

Then you can use this `fit` vectorizer on any new data source via the `transform()` method.

You can obtain the vocabulary produced by the fit (i.e. mapping of word to token ID) via `vectorizer.vocabulary_` (assuming you name your `CountVectorizer` the name `vectorizer`.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> tags = [
  "python, tools",
  "linux, tools, ubuntu",
  "distributed systems, linux, networking, tools",
]

>>> list_of_new_documents = [
  ["python, chicken"],
  ["linux, cow, ubuntu"],
  ["machine learning, bird, fish, pig"]

]

>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
>>> vect = CountVectorizer()
>>> tags = vect.fit_transform(tags)

# vocabulary learned by CountVectorizer (vect)
>>> print(vect.vocabulary_)
{'python': 3, 'tools': 5, 'linux': 1, 'ubuntu': 6, 'distributed': 0, 'systems': 4, 'networking': 2}

# counts for tags
>>> tags.toarray()
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]], dtype=int64)

# to use `transform`, `list_of_new_documents` should be a list of strings 
# `itertools.chain` flattens shallow lists more efficiently than list comprehensions

>>> from itertools import chain
>>> new_docs = list(chain.from_iterable(list_of_new_documents)
>>> new_docs = vect.transform(new_docs)

# finally, counts for new_docs!
>>> new_docs.toarray()
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

To verify that `CountVectorizer` is using the vocabulary learned from `tags` on `new_docs`: print `vect.vocabulary_` again or compare the output of `new_docs.toarray()` to that of `tags.toarray()`