# Provide vocaburary of word with space to scikit-learn CountVectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Referring to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22920801/can-i-use-countvectorizer-in-scikit-learn-to-count-frequency-of-documents-that-w). I am wondering how we provide vocabulary of word with space to `CountVectorizer` model e.g. `distributed systems` or `machine learning`? Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

tags = [
  "python, tools",
  "linux, tools, ubuntu",
  "distributed systems, linux, networking, tools",
]

vocabulary = list(map(lambda x: x.split(', '), tags))
vocabulary = list(np.unique(list(chain(*vocabulary))))
```

We can provide this vocabulary list to the model

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vec = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocabulary)
print(vec.fit_transform(tags).toarray())
```

Here, I lost the count of word `distributed systems` (first column). The result is as follow:

```
[[0 0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0 1 1]
 [0 1 1 0 1 0]]
```

Do I have to change `token_pattern` or somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think essentially you have already pre-defined your vocabularies to analyze and you want to tokenize your tags by splitting ', '.

You can trick the `CountVectorizer` to do that by:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vec = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocabulary, tokenizer=lambda x: x.split(', '))
print(vec.fit_transform(tags).toarray())
```

, which gives:

```
[[0 0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0 1 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Zichen, this is what I'm looking for. Makes the problem very handy using `tokenizer`